# How would I write negation of the following questions in the mathematical notation and are they true or false statements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

for all x there exists y         ( 2x = y )

there exists x for all y         ( 2x = y  )

there exists x there exists y for all z     (yz = x)

I am not sure about how would I go about doing this problem. I think the first two my statement if false, but I am unsure. I have tried negating it but can't understand how to do it. I know that negation is opposite of a statement, but how would I apply this is math.

Comment: Just to be clear, are these three separate problems?

Comment: yes they are the same

Answer (score 1):

It might help to see what applies to what, so you can better understand where the negations would hit. For example, in the first statement the quantifier "for all $x$" then applies to "there exists a $y$ such that $2x = y$", which means that (if it's true), you can pick a value of $x$, and having done so you can always find a $y$ that makes $2x = y$ true. In formal notation, we'd write $\forall x (\exists y (2x = y))$. By comparison, the second statement is defined by "there exists a $y$", then inside that we have "such that for all $x$, $2x = y$" - which means that there is one universal value of $y$ that makes $2x = y$ true regardless of $x$. In notation, that's $\exists y(\forall x (2x = y))$.

When you negate, the opposite of "this is true for all $x$" is "there exists a value of $x$ where this is not true" - i.e. $\lnot \forall x P(x)$ is the same as $\exists x \lnot P(x)$. So if a "for all" statement is false, you can prove that by finding a single counterexample. On the other hand, to prove a "there exists" statement false, you have to show that it breaks down for every possible value - i.e. the negation of $\exists x P(x)$ is $\forall x \lnot P(x)$.

Comment: Wait I Still Don't understand

Comment: Which part? Do you understand the difference between "for all $x$ there exists $y$" and "there exists $y$ such that for all $x$"?